# Creating a SQLite database for the game Tic Tac toe and connecting it to the main Activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a SQLite database for the game Tic Tac Toe on Android Studio that has the names and score of the players. Every time a user win, a point is added on the scoreboard.

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to add? You should be able to get all the informations from the [Android SQLite docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)

Answer (score 2):

### Stage 1 - Database Design

First design the database, you have identified Data as User name, and score, assuming you don't want historical data then a single table would suffice.

So design would be a table, perhaps called scoreboard, with columns :-

- username
- score and
- To perhaps aid future changes a column name id that uniquely identifies a user (e.g. say you had two Toms or even two Tom smiths), this identifier (which is generally available) will be an alias of rowid. As Cursor Adapters require the id to be named **_id** then that will be used.

As such you could have a table that is created using the following SQL :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scoreboard 
    (
        _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        username TEXT,
        score INTEGER
    );
```

### Stage 2 - Creating the Database

When getting started with SQLite for Android it is probably best to utilise a subclass of **SQLiteOpenHelper** as what many refer to as the ***DBHelper***.

So create a class say **DBHelper.java** which extends the **SQLiteOpenHelper** class.

- Note you must include overrides for the `onCreate` method and the `onUpgrade` method.
- If using Android Studio when adding a new class;

  - input, DBHelper in the **Name* field,
  - type **SQLiteOpenHelper** in the **Superclass** field (by the time you've typed SQL you will see SQLiteOpenHelper double click is) and
  - then tick/check the **Show Select Overrides Dialog**.
  - Click **OK**

You will presented with the Overrides Dialog select (Ctrl + CLick) the following 3 (SQLiteOpenHelper(context"Context,name:String,factory:CursorFactory,version:int) will be selected) :-

- SQLiteOpenHelper(context"Context,name:String,factory:CursorFactory,version:int)
- onCreate(.....
- onUpgrade(.....

Then click **OK**.

You will then have :-

> ```
> public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
>     public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
>         super(context, name, factory, version);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
>
>     }
> }
> ```

#### Define some constants

Between the class and the constructor add some constants so you have a single source for names of tables/columns etc e.g. :-

```
public static final String DBNAME = "tictactoe.db"; // Database name
public static final int DBVERSION = 1;              // Database version #
public static final  String TB_SCOREBOARD = "scoreboard"; // table name
public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // use default id column name
public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE = "score";
```

#### Ready to create the Table

The `onCreate` method will be called when you try to open the database (and the database is actually created). Generally it is here that you create the tables.

- **Note** one of the more common issues newcomers have is that they think that `onCreate` runs every time a database is opened. It is not it only runs once when the database is first created.
- as such any changes (say you add a new column) WILL NOT BE MADE if the databade still exists (easiest solution when developing an App is to delete the App's Data or uninstall the App and rerun the App).

So in the `onCreate` method :-

- create a String of the SQL to create the table (i.e. the CREATE IF NOT EXISTS.... previously shown). However, do so utilising the CONSTANTS (see below).

  - call the `SQLiteDatabase` **`execSQL`** method to run the SQL.

#### Alter the constructor's signature (make it easier to call).

As the database name and version are known (they are constant) and that a cursor factory needn't be used (null will signify this) the super call in the constructor can be replaced with :-

```
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
```

Therefore the signature for the DBHelper class can be changed to :-

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
}
```

So the DBHelper class in full (at present) can be :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "tictactoe.db"; // Database name
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;              // Database version #
    public static final  String TB_SCOREBOARD = "scoreboard"; // table name
    public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // use default id column name
    public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE = "score";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                TB_SCOREBOARD + // The table name
                "(" +
                COL_SCOREBOARD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + //The _id column
                COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME + " TEXT, " + // username column
                COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE + " INTEGER" + // score column (no trailing comma as last)
                ")" ;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

### Stage 3 - TEST what has been so far

Believe it or not the above is sufficient to create the database and the table and hence the columns within the table (not to actually add any data or anything useful but at least).

Typically you would use the database in an activity. For the purposes of this testing a basic **MainActivity** will be used.

It's actually very simple we just create a DBHelper instance (passing the Context).

**BUT** doing so won't create a database it's only when either the getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase methods are called that an attempt is made to **open or create** the database. So a second line will do this (could be done in one line) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this); // get DBHelper instance
        mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(); // force an open (wouldn't normally do this)
    }
}
```

- **Note** you wouldn't normally have a call to `getWritableDatabase` as will be seen each method to access the table(s) will do this, so the very first time one of these would result in the `onCreate` method being called.
- **Note** there is much confusion with `getReadableDatabase`, in short it doesn't make it so you can't update/change data unless the database can only be read.

  - i.e. `getReadabledatabase` will get a writable database unless in the very rare scenario the database can only be read (when getWritableDatabase would fail with an unable to open database error).
  - **VERY RARELY** is there any use coding `getReadableDatabase`.

**Do the above and Run the App** - nothing much will happen, but hopefully it shouldn't crash.

Now if you can (depends on emulator (I use genymotion which gives you root access)) use Android Studion's **Device Explorer* to look at **`/data/data/<your_package_name>/databases/`** and hopefully you will see :-

[image]

- package and actual database are highlighted.
- database is just a file (can be copied and opened in other SQLite tools (can even be copied to android (emulator/device permitting))).
- journal is SQLite's file that records what's being done and in cases of errors allows data to be rolled back (i.e. just accept it exists).
- A believe that size should be 16K (depends upon data and structure of the database). It shouldn't be 0 though.

If you can't use Device Explorer then you can go into settings and check the App's data (if you have other uses of App data then check subtract this (check before running)), it should be 0 (after subtracting other data). in which case that's an indication that the database exists.

### Stage 4 - Adding and Manipulating Data

At this stage a database exists with a table but no data itself exists. So a means of adding data (inserting rows) (a table has rows a row consisting of the columns as per the definition of the table).

It's no use adding data unless that data can be accessed so a means of extracting the data (querying) is required.

As a method of changing (updating) the score is required a means of doing this is required.

So what is needed now are 3 things :-

- an `insertRow` method
- a `getAllData` method (say to list scoreboard)
- a `updateScore` method (which will adjust the score according to a number)

Typically such methods are added to the Database Helper (so they will be here)

#### The `insertRow` method

When inserting a row we need to add the name and the score (we could have defined the score column as `score INTEGER DEFAULT 0` and then just the name would be required).

Although you don't know it yet **id**'s can be very useful so the method will return the id of the newly inserted row, which due to using _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (**and specifically this** (or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT). will be generated automatically (i.e. the _id column is an alias of the very special but normally hidden **rowid** column (see link below for more info on rowid)).

- *the latter, AUTOINCREMENT, is very rarely needed but is seen very often* more here [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), this also explains **rowid**)

So a method such as the following could be added :-

```
public long insertRow(String username, int initial_score) {
    // SQL equivalent of :-
    // INSERT INTO scoreboard (username,score) VALUES('the user name',0)
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); // Used by convenience method for column/value pairs
    cv.put(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE,username); // The username to be added
    cv.put(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE,initial_score); // The score to be added
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Get a SQLiteDatabase instance
    return db.insert(TB_SCOREBOARD,null,cv); // Insert it using conveniece method
    /*
        Note if row cannot be inserted then return will be -1
        If inserted the id will be returned, 
        first ever insert will be 1, 
        then likely 2
        then likely 3
        NEVER ASSUME 1,2,3.......... though
        ALWAYS ASSUME IT WILL BE A UNIQUE VALUE
        i.e. NEVER CODE SPECIFIC ID's
     */
}
```

You may wish to read [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

The Activity could use this using for example :-

```
        mDBHlpr.insertRow("Rumplestiltskin the 3rd",10000000); // The winner :)
        mDBHlpr.insertRow("Fred Blogs",0); // New user would normally start with score 0
```

- Adds 2 rows first with high score, 2nd as you would probably add a new user

#### The getAllData method

With Android you extract data into what's called a Cursor, which is like a spreadsheet it has rows and columns (columns as you specify so they needn't be all the columns, can also be other columns (e.g. derived/calculated or from other tables).

You create a Cursor (at least a normal one) by querying the table or tables in the database (note this doesn't cover all aspects). So use will be made of the convenience `query` method (well 1 of the 4) using :-

```
public Cursor getAlldata() {

    // The columns to retrieve
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            COL_SCOREBOARD_ID,
            COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME,
            COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE
    };
    // NOTE normally for all columns you would use the above but
    // instead pass null as the 2nd parameter to the query method
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
            TB_SCOREBOARD,
            columns,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
}
```

You may wish to read [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

This could be used in the Activity along the lines of :-

```
    Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getAlldata();
    csr.close(); //YOU SHOULD ALWAYS CLOSE A CURSOR WHEN DONE WITH IT
```

#### The updateScore method

Without getting too complex and sticking to convenience methods the process of updating a score will :-

1. get the old score (according to id)
2. update the new score by adding the new score (if it's minus then reducing the score)

As such 2 parameters are required the **id** and the **amount to adjust** the **score** by. 
 -Id's should be long (you will see many uses of int but long copes with all possible id's).
 -adjustment will be integer (long if very high scores are expected)

#### A diversion for getScoreById method

As getting a user's score may be useful another method will be created to do this. This also makes use of a Cursor that selects specific data rather than all via an SQL WHERE clause. So a method **`getScoreById`** will also be created. This will return the current score as an int and is passed a long as the id.

This could be :-

```
public int getScoreById(long id) {
    int rv = -1; // just in case the id doesn't exist return -1 so invalid adjustment can be detected
    String[] columns = new String[]{COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE}; // only want the score
    String whereclause = COL_SCOREBOARD_ID + "=?"; // will be WHERE _id=? (? replaced by respective whereargs element)
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}; // ? will be replaced with id
    Cursor csr = this.getWritableDatabase().query(
            TB_SCOREBOARD,
            columns,
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        //rv = csr.getInt(0); // Hard coded column offsets bad so :-
        rv = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE));
    }
    csr.close(); // Done with the cursor so close it
    return rv; // return the current score
}
```

#### Back to the upDateScore method

Now that the score can be retrieved by the id via the `getScoreById` method then the the `updateScore` method could be :-

```
public boolean updateScore(long id, int adjustment) {

    int newscore = getScoreById(id) + adjustment; // get the new score

    // Check that the new score is valid (i.e. greater than 0)
    // If it's invalid then don't do update by returning false but after
    // issuing a message to the log (for development should be removed for production)
    if (newscore < 0) {
        Log.d("INVALIDSCORE",
                "An invalid new score (less than 0) was returned. Update cancelled.");
        return false;
    }
    // Prepare to use the update convenience method
    String whereclause = COL_SCOREBOARD_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE,newscore);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // WARNING without a WHERE clause update would update ALL ROWS
    // update returns number of rows updated as an int, so if this is
    // greater than 0 true is returned else false.
    return db.update(TB_SCOREBOARD,cv,whereclause,whereargs) > 0;
}
```

So the whole DBHelper class could be :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "tictactoe.db"; // Database name
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;              // Database version #
    public static final  String TB_SCOREBOARD = "scoreboard"; // table name
    public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // use default id column name
    public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE = "score";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                TB_SCOREBOARD + // The table name
                "(" +
                COL_SCOREBOARD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + //The _id column
                COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME + " TEXT, " + // username column
                COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE + " INTEGER" + // score column (no trailing comma as last)
                ")" ;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertRow(String username, int initial_score) {
        // SQL equivalent of :-
        // INSERT INTO scoreboard (username,score) VALUES('the user name',0)
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); // Used by convenience method for column/value pairs
        cv.put(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE,username); // The username to be added
        cv.put(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE,initial_score); // The score to be added
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Get a SQLiteDatabase instance
        return db.insert(TB_SCOREBOARD,null,cv); // Insert it
        /*
            Note if row cannot be inserted then return will be -1
            If insert the id will be returned,
            first ever insert will be 1,
            then likely 2
            then likely 3
            NEVER ASSUME 1,2,3.......... though
            ALWAYS ASSUME IT WILL BE A UNIQUE VALUE
            i.e. NEVER CODE SPECIFIC ID's
         */
    }

    public Cursor getAlldata() {

        // The columns to retrieve
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                COL_SCOREBOARD_ID,
                COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME,
                COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE
        };
        // NOTE normally for all columns you would use the above but
        // instead pass null as the 2nd parameter to the query method
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TB_SCOREBOARD,
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }

    public boolean updateScore(long id, int adjustment) {

        int newscore = getScoreById(id) + adjustment; // get the new score

        // Check that the new score is valid (i.e. greater than 0)
        // If it's invalid then don't do update by returning false but after
        // issuing a message to the log (for development should be removed for production)
        if (newscore < 0) {
            Log.d("INVALIDSCORE",
                    "An invalid new score (less than 0) was returned. Update cancelled.");
            return false;
        }
        // Prepare to use the update convenience method
        String whereclause = COL_SCOREBOARD_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE,newscore);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // WARNING without a WHERE clause update would update ALL ROWS
        // update returns number of rows updated as an int, so if this is
        // greater than 0 true is returned else false.
        return db.update(TB_SCOREBOARD,cv,whereclause,whereargs) > 0;
    }

    public int getScoreById(long id) {
        int rv = -1; // just in case the id doesn't exist return -1 so invalid adjustment can be detected
        String[] columns = new String[]{COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE}; // only want the score
        String whereclause = COL_SCOREBOARD_ID + "=?"; // will be WHERE _id=? (? replaced by respective whereargs element)
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}; // ? will be replaced with id
        Cursor csr = this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TB_SCOREBOARD,
                columns,
                whereclause,
                whereargs,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            //rv = csr.getInt(0); // Hard coded column offsets bad so :-
            rv = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE));
        }
        csr.close(); // Done with the cursor so close it
        return rv; // return the current score
    }
}
```

### Stage 5 - Testing

The activity (based upon a new empty project) could now be :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this); // get DBHelper instance
        //mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(); // force an open (wouldn't normally do this) Not needed now

        mDBHlpr.insertRow("Rumplestiltskin the 3rd",10000000); // The winner :)
        mDBHlpr.insertRow("Fred Blogs",0); // New user would normally start with score 0

        mDBHlpr.updateScore(1,-9999999); //Set Rumplestiltskins's score to 0
                                                       // NOTE id should be 1 BUT hard coding id's is
                                                       // should be avoided (just used for demo purposes)
        mDBHlpr.updateScore(2,1);        // Increment Fred's score (see above re hard coded id's)


        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getAlldata();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Do something with the Extracted Data
        while (csr.moveToNext()) { // Loop through all rows
            long userid = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_SCOREBOARD_ID));
            String username = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_SCOREBOARD_USERNAME));
            int userscore = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_SCOREBOARD_SCORE));
            sb.append("\n\tUsername=");
            sb.append(username);
            sb.append((" (ID="));
            sb.append(userid);
            sb.append(") Score=");
            sb.append(userscore);
            sb.append(".");
        }
        csr.close();
        Log.d("SCOREBOARD",sb.toString());
    }
}
```

- Note cursor handling added

### Result

- **note** after numerous runs which will add duplicate usernames but with different id's)

:-

```
05-18 12:09:46.750 3018-3018/? D/INVALIDSCORE: An invalid new score (less than 0) was returned. Update cancelled.
05-18 12:09:46.754 3018-3018/? D/SCOREBOARD:    Username=null (ID=1) Score=1.
        Username=null (ID=2) Score=5.
        Username=null (ID=3) Score=10000000.
        Username=null (ID=4) Score=0.
        Username=null (ID=5) Score=10000000.
        Username=null (ID=6) Score=0.
        Username=null (ID=7) Score=10000000.
        Username=null (ID=8) Score=0.
        Username=null (ID=9) Score=10000000.
        Username=null (ID=10) Score=0.
```

- Invalid Score is because once ID 1 is down to 1 the adjustment of -99999999 will be less than 0.
- ID 2's score is 5 due to 5 runs (i.e. 10 rows/users).

### Note

**The above is a fully working albeit it not that useful, introduction/answer. As such any subsequent questions should really be other questions on Stack Overflow.***